Problem fitting two divs side by side in HTML
I am trying to make two divs stand side by side on the webpage using the float property, as described here. However, it isn't working as expected. What do I need to do to fix the issue?
(Please note that I am following a tutorial and thus do not want to use Flexbox or grid for this purpose.)
What I want is something like this:

what I'm getting is something like this:

Here is the HTML for my webpage:


body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  color: lightsalmon;
  text-align: center;
}

.float-container {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.float-container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.float-container p {
  color: brown;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}

.float-child {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid salmon;
}
<h1>Lasagna</h1>
<div class="float-container">
  <img src="images/lasagna.jpg" alt="Lasagna">
  <p>This classic lasagna recipe features a meaty sauce layered with noodles and cheese. It’s perfect for feeding a crowd or freezing for later.</p>
  <div class="float-child">
    <div class="first">
      <h3>Ingredients</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>1 pound lean ground beef</li>
        <li>1 egg (beaten)</li>
        <li>15 ounces part-skim ricotta cheese</li>
        <li>¼ cup fresh parsley (chopped)</li>
        <li>2 ½ cups shredded low-moisture part-skim mozzarella cheese (divided)</li>
        <li>½ cup grated Parmesan cheese (divided)</li>
        <li>24 ounces CLASSICO Tomato And Basil Pasta Sauce</li>
        <li>1 cup water</li>
        <li>12 lasagna noodles (uncooked)</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="float-child">
    <div class="second">
      <h3>Steps</h3>
      <ol>
        <li>Heat oven to 350°F.</li>
        <li>Brown meat in large skillet on medium-high heat. Meanwhile, combine egg, ricotta, parsley, 1-1/4 cups mozzarella and 1/4 cup Parmesan.</li>
        <li>Drain meat; return to skillet. Stir in pasta sauce. Add 1 cup water to empty sauce jar; cover with lid and shake well. Add to meat mixture; stir until blended.</li>
        <li>Spread 1 cup meat sauce onto bottom of 13x9-inch baking dish sprayed with cooking spray; top with layers of 3 lasagna noodles, 1/3 of the ricotta mixture and 1 cup of the remaining meat sauce. Repeat layers twice. Top with remaining noodles, meat
          sauce and cheeses. Cover with foil sprayed with cooking spray.</li>
        <li>Bake 1 hour or until heated through, removing foil after 45 min. Let stand 15 min. before cutting to serve.</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




note that I am following a tutorial and thus do not want to use Flexbox or grid for this purpose. --> I highly recommend you stop following that tutorial

You need to have the size include padding since the total width exceeds 100% of the parent's width which makes the second float wrap.
box-sizing: border-box;

If you change the HTML or CSS later, make sure the parent element .float-container has enough width and is not influenced by other CSS properties or parent elements.


body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  color: lightsalmon;
  text-align: center;
}

.float-container {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.float-container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.float-container p {
  color: brown;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}

.float-child {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid salmon;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in the width */
}
<h1>Lasagna</h1>
<div class="float-container">
  <img src="images/lasagna.jpg" alt="Lasagna">
  <p>This classic lasagna recipe features a meaty sauce layered with noodles and cheese. It’s perfect for feeding a crowd or freezing for later.</p>
  <div class="float-child">
    <div class="first">
      <h3>Ingredients</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>1 pound lean ground beef</li>
        <li>1 egg (beaten)</li>
        <li>15 ounces part-skim ricotta cheese</li>
        <li>¼ cup fresh parsley (chopped)</li>
        <li>2 ½ cups shredded low-moisture part-skim mozzarella cheese (divided)</li>
        <li>½ cup grated Parmesan cheese (divided)</li>
        <li>24 ounces CLASSICO Tomato And Basil Pasta Sauce</li>
        <li>1 cup water</li>
        <li>12 lasagna noodles (uncooked)</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="float-child">
    <div class="second">
      <h3>Steps</h3>
      <ol>
        <li>Heat oven to 350°F.</li>
        <li>Brown meat in large skillet on medium-high heat. Meanwhile, combine egg, ricotta, parsley, 1-1/4 cups mozzarella and 1/4 cup Parmesan.</li>
        <li>Drain meat; return to skillet. Stir in pasta sauce. Add 1 cup water to empty sauce jar; cover with lid and shake well. Add to meat mixture; stir until blended.</li>
        <li>Spread 1 cup meat sauce onto bottom of 13x9-inch baking dish sprayed with cooking spray; top with layers of 3 lasagna noodles, 1/3 of the ricotta mixture and 1 cup of the remaining meat sauce. Repeat layers twice. Top with remaining noodles, meat
          sauce and cheeses. Cover with foil sprayed with cooking spray.</li>
        <li>Bake 1 hour or until heated through, removing foil after 45 min. Let stand 15 min. before cutting to serve.</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



To float one left and this other right, will solve it too, but can result in unaligned divs when the viewport gets so narrow, that they wrap.

Because when they break, the one floating left will stick to the left of the container and the one floated right, to the right. That can make them unaligned. Also why use more CSS to fix a simple problem?
